# Understanding why the given function in harmonic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

From L. Evans' book on PDE's:

> **Definition**
>
> The function
>
> $$\Phi(x) = \begin{cases} -\frac{1}{2\pi} \log|x| & (n=2) \\ \frac{1}{n(n-2)\alpha(n)} \frac{1}{\lvert x \rvert^{n-2}}
> & (n\geq3)\end{cases}$$
>
> defined for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n, \ x \neq 0$, is the fundamental solution of Laplace's equation.

---

By construction, the function $x \mapsto \Phi(x)$ is harmonic for $x\neq0$. If we shift the origin to a new point $y$, the PDE $\Delta u=0$ is unchanged, and so $x\mapsto\Phi(x-y)$ is also harmonic as a function of $x$, $x\neq y$. Let us now take a $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and note that the mapping $x\mapsto\Phi(x-y)f(y)$, $x\neq y$ is harmonic for each $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and thus so is the sum of finitely many such expressions built for different points $y$.

Now I know that a function is harmonic if it is $\mathbf{C}^2$ and it satisfies $\Delta u=0$, and that a set of harmonic functions can be seen as a vector space, i.e. linear combinations of harmonic functions are again harmonic functions, but I don't know how to show the function $x\mapsto\Phi(x)$ is harmonic, nor how to show that the mapping $x\mapsto\Phi(x-y)f(y)$, $x\neq y$ is harmonic for each $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, when $x\mapsto\Phi(x)$ is harmonic.

Comment: What is your question? $\Phi$ is not harmonic on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, nor is $\Phi(x-y)f(y)$. it’s the fundamental solution because $\Delta \Phi = \delta_0$ in the distributional sense where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac delta. In particular, $u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x-y)f(y)dy$ solves the Poisson equation $\Delta u = f$.

Comment: @kieransquared According to Lawrence Evans' book it is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^n-{0}$, my question is how do we show it is indeed harmonic. My text is a literal copy from the book paragraph 2.2.1. a. Derivation of fundamental solution and 2.2.1. b. Poisson's equation, which I consider to be correct..

Comment: Oh, to show that $\Delta \Phi = 0$ away from zero you can compute the Laplacian directly, it’s just a calculation. Derivatives remain unchanged under translation (by the chain rule) so the same applies for $\Phi(x-y)$. The fact that $\Phi(x-y) f(y)$ is harmonic as a function of $x$ then follows since $f(y)$ is independent of $x$.

Comment: Ah so it just blandly computing it directly, was hoping for it to be some nice property, the last remark on the $f(y)$ is also clear, thanks! @kieransquared